# Cake PHP 2.10 paginator not joining models

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to join my `ApplicationPayday` model to my `Application` in my Cake PHP 2.10 application via the `joins` property in my paginator. For some reason though, I'm only seeing the `Application` and not my joined Payday, what am I missing as this works if I do a regular model query outside of pagination.

```php
// define pagination settings
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'maxLimit' => 20,
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'tlp_application_paydays',
                        'alias' => 'ApplicationPayday',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'ApplicationPayday.application_id = Application.id'
                        )
                ),
        ),
        'order' => array(
                'Application.id' => 'desc'
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
);

// run query to get applications via paginated settings
$applications = $this->Paginator->paginate('Application');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($applications);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Cake 2x is extremely old, not sure it is even supported through security updates any more? In this case I assume the recursive -1 is at fault as that will only return the top level model

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing recursive = -1 and use contain() like this:

```
$this->Application->contain([
    'ApplicationPayday',
]);
```

Read more about contain() here: https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html